# Production of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism

EM waves are classified into types according to the frequency of the wave: these types include, in order of increasing frequency, radio waves, microwaves, infrared radiation, visible light, ultraviolet radiation, X-rays and gamma rays.

Its said that electromagnetic waves are produced by the accelerating/oscillating charges. So suppose i have a conductor connected to a AC source.

Can i ideally produce all these electromagnetic waves of different frequencies by changing the frequency of current/voltage to the conductor ? How the frequency of the electromagnetic waves is related to the frequency of the alternating current in the conductor ?

Is there any equation that relates the two frequencies ?

Or simply to generate the electromagnetic wave of 8×10^14 Hz (light), i will have to oscillate the charges with the frequency of 8×10^14 Hz in the conductor ?

Or all these electromagnetic waves will be produced in any other different ways ?

Comment: The frequency of electromagnetic wave is equal to the frequency of the current inducing it.

Comment: You need to understand a little bit bout wavelength and the relationship between wavelength and antenna size. Typically, the longer the wavelength, the larger the antenna, and the smaller the wavelength, the smaller the antenna. For frequencies up to GHz, it is possible to make wire antennas. At some point, though, it becomes less practical, and you move into what is often considered to be the realm of optics. For very low frequencies, practical antennas become impossibly large. That is just the basic concept.

Comment: Light waves cannot be produced by "conductors" because the size of the resonator needed for that is in the range of the electron shell of an atom.

Comment: @Janka, what about a tungsten filament in a lightbulb?

Comment: @jsotola there's no resonating here; the electrons in the metal don't actually oscillate at light frequencies (or only if you model the energy released as a photon as coming from phonons, which are quantum "models" of oscillatory energy being exchanged within a structure).

Comment: @jsotola That light comes from the random collisions of the electrons (more generally, charges), not the oscillating current. The distribution depends on the temperature of the filament, because that's what increases the relative velocities of individual charges in the filament - the current is only there to drive the temperature up, any other heat source would work just as well (as in e.g. a fire).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can i ideally produce all these electromagnetic waves of different frequencies by changing the frequency of current/voltage to the conductor ?

That is necessary, but not sufficient: your conductor must be designed to *radiate*. That's why antennas have a specific shape. Typically, an antenna is somewhere between ¼ and a full free-space wavelength of the radiated wave; but that's really just a very general rule of thumb. Some antennas can be made much smaller, others are built much larger for complex engineering reasons.

> How the frequency of the electromagnetic waves is related to the frequency of the alternating current in the conductor ?

They are one and the same.

> Is there any equation that relates the two frequencies ?

\$f_\text{current} = f_\text{wave}\$. No magic here.

> Or simply to generate the electromagnetic wave of 8×10^14 Hz (light), i will have to oscillate the charges with the frequency of 8×10^14 Hz in the conductor ?

In principle, yes. But:

It's technically impossible to do that with what you think of when you think of AC sources.

Instead, light is emitted, for example in LEDs, when electrons need to lose energy. Sadly, you're leaving the realm of Maxwell's equations (which describe electromagnetism on any non-quantum-sized scale), and enter the world of solid state quantum physics. So, while it would work that way, if you could find something fast enough to work as a source of AC, but smaller than the wavelength of light … which doesn't happen; metal material with conduction bands quickly becomes larger than that, and the properties of semiconductors and electron gases simply aren't very similar to what we're used to at lower frequencies. I can't build a \$10^{14}\,\text{Hz}\$ oscillator; effects that are very benign and irrelevant at lower frequencies dominate here, and none of our electronics still work like they should.

> Or all these electromagnetic waves will be produced in any other different ways ?

Yes. You probably have heard of *light sources* before: candles, incandescent lamps, LEDs and lasers, among a couple other things.

You're deep into the world of photonics here.

Comment: You did not even mention gamma rays, normally produced by black-holes accelerating matter, or the birth of a black hole, or hydrogen bombs. Not a DIY project for sure.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any equation that relates the two frequencies ?

Yes, the two frequencies are equal.

> Or simply to generate the electromagnetic wave of 8×10^14 Hz (light), i will have to oscillate the charges with the frequency of 8×10^14 Hz in the conductor ?

Yes, but of course this is impractical.

> Or all these electromagnetic waves will be produced in any other different ways ?

You can use some process that causes the molecules in some substance (like in the filament of an incandescent bulb or in an LED) to stimulate the high frequency.

Answer (score 2):

A [free-electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser) does in fact oscillate electrons at any frequency you like, and thus produces EM radiation at any frequency from microwave all the way up to X-ray.  The very short explanation of how this is possible is, you have a long tube with alternating-polarity magnetic fields down its length, with a period on the order of centimeters, and then you fire a beam of electrons down the tube at a significant fraction of the speed of light; [Lorentz contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) means the electrons see the magnetic field oscillating with a much higher frequency, and that's the frequency they themselves oscillate at, and thus the frequency of light they emit.

I don't know how tunable any *one* FEL is, though; the optimal design for a microwave FEL is probably quite different from the optimal design for an X-ray FEL.  And these are laboratory machines the size of a small building.

Comment: You don't even need a laser - any synchrotron radiator will do. Free-electron lasers are themselves using the synchrotron radiation mechanism.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, I guess the machine I described is just a generic linear synchrotron source; you need more stuff to make it lase.  The concept is indelibly associated with free-electron lasers in my head because the lab next door to the one I worked in as an undergraduate was built around a FEL.